# Javascript truthy equivalent to not undefined, not null and not empty string?

Tags: javascript

I found the following legacy Javascript code:

```js
function doSomething(parameter) {
    if (parameter != null && parameter != undefined && parameter != '') {
        ...
    }
}
```

I wonder if it is equal to check

```js
if(parameter) {
    ...
}
```

i.e. if it is equal to check if the parameter is truthy. Is there a case when this is not equal?

Comment: Type `undefined === true` into a browser console

Comment: @RGraham undefined is falsy, what shall your comment say to my question? Am i missing something?

Comment: these statements are not equivalent for `0`, `NaN` and `false`.

Comment: @thg435 only for `NaN`. `false` and `0` fall in `parameter != ''` (see my answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No is not the same. In case of `parameter = NaN` your IF is `true` while `if(paramater)` is evalueted to `false`.

In fact:

```
var parameter = NaN;
if (parameter != null && parameter != undefined && parameter != '') {
    console.log("first if");
}
if(parameter) 
     console.log("second if");
```

just log `first if`.

In the case of `0` or `false` the two `IF` make the same result caused by not strict equality of `parameter != ''`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to NaN, now I can martyr myself by deciding whether the orginal coder really intended that or not. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Check the link about **Converting to Boolean** part

http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/

Only `NaN`, `0`, `false`, `null`,`undefined`, `''` will be converted to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript there are few values are converted as `boolean false` else almost all are converted to `true`

```
undefined
The empty string ""
null
The number 0
The number NaN
The boolean false
```

so it better to have

```
if(!parameter)
{
  // your code
}
```

Comment: You are right that one often needs `!parameter`, but in this case with empty string however, you are not right (`!'' === true`). I don't understand why this answer is upvoted in the context of this question.

Comment: @jan when you use strict equal to then compares type, i mentioned that  comparision result is implicitly converted to boolean false, not the values used to compare.

Answer (score 0):

It's all the same as you're using loose comparison `!=` not strict `!==` so `undefined == null`, and `'' == 0`, `false == ''`, etc.

**Edit:** As pointed out, they're not exactly the same. As a general rule though you'd use either:

```
if (parameter != null) {

}
```

Where `undefined == null` so you check for both. Or:

```
if (parameter) {

}
```

Which tests any falsey value such as `null`, `undefined`, empty string, zero...

Comment: So is this a "yes" and there is no case where the checks don't equal?

Comment: There are specific rules. But as a general rule, you usually check in one of the ways I posted above, plus a third way (irrelevant to the question) that tests for existence, with the `typeof` operator. It depends on the situation.